# Django's password reset URL customized isn't loading after the first try

Tags: python, django, backend

I'm using Django's password-reset URLs and I have created my own templates for them, but after I put in my Email address it redirects me to the default templates instead of redirecting me to my custom template.

urls.py

```
path('password_reset/',
auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="authsystem/password_reset.html"),
name='password_reset'),

path('password_reset/done',
auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="authsystem/password_reset_sent.html"),
name='password_reset_done'),

path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="authsystem/password_reset_form.html"),
name='password_reset_confirm'),

path('reset/done/',
auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="authsystem/password_reset_done.html"),
name='password_reset_complete'),
```

After It moves from 'password_reset.html' it's supposed to render 'password_reset_sent.html' but it renders Django's default template.

[image: Template folder]

Answer (score 0):

Without changing url patterns you can create the custom template for PasswordResetDoneView at: templates/registration/password_reset_done.html.

Otherwise you can subclass PasswordResetDoneView:

**Views**

```
class CustomPasswordResetDoneView(PasswordResetDoneView):
    template_name = 'authsystem/password_reset_sent.html'
```

**Urls**

```
path('password_reset/done', CustomPasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
```